# Google Compute Engine: how to delete access config with whitespace in name ("External NAT")?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to delete the access config for one of my Google Compute Engine instances, and as described in [some of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#IP_assign), the access config for my instance is named "External NAT" rather than the default "external-nat". When I try to run:

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config my-instance-name --access-config-name="External NAT"
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete-access-config) unrecognized arguments: NAT
```

I'm assuming the error of the space in "External NAT". Seems like this should be a simple fix but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You added "=" when in fact it is not needed. It worked as follows :

$ `gcloud compute instances delete-access-config test-instance --access-config-name "External NAT"`

Output:

Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project/zones/europe-west1-c/instances/test-instance].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marius, but I tried that and still get the same error.

Comment: Strange that it did not work for you. You can also try gcutil like this :  $ gcutil deleteaccessconfig --access_config_name 'External NAT' instance_name  . That worked for me with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config test-instance --access-config-name="External NAT" --network-interface="nic0" --zone="us-east1-b"
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: network-interface and zone variables are required, when using access-config-name variable