# delete-access-config failed because of "unrecognized arguments: NAT"

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config gcc1 --access-config-name "External NAT"
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete-access-config) unrecognized
>   arguments: NAT

It's just like the whitespace who cause the error.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplcate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591239/google-compute-engine-how-to-delete-access-config-with-whitespace-in-name-ext

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a whitespace in the name. In the example given [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-access-config), they use `external-nat` as the name. (Note the dash)